# Match up the contents of two files

Tags: linux, bash

I have two files: one contains a list of AP names, and another list contains AP names again, but this time the controller IP for each AP is listed before the AP's name.

File 1:

```
AP1
AP2
Ap3
AP4
Ap5
Ap6
...
```

File 2:

```
1.1.1.1,Ap1
2.2.2.2,Ap2
3.3.3.3,Ap3
4.4.4.4,Ap4
6.6.6.6,Ap6
...
```

How can I match up the names from file 1 with the names in file 2 so that the output resembles the following?

```
1.1.1.1,Ap1
2.2.2.2,Ap2
3.3.3.3,Ap3
4.4.4.4,Ap4
IP Not Found,Ap5
6.6.6.6,Ap6
```

I was thinking that I could use the `comm` command, but I do not know of a good way to only compare the names and not the IPs. I could also just grep for every single name, but that would take forever (there are around 8,000 AP names).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `join` command will do the job (note that both files have to be sorted by AP name first; your example data already is, but if your real-world data isn't, run the first file through `sort -f`, and the second file through `sort -f -t , -k 2`).

```
join -i -t , -1 1 -2 2 -a 1 -o 2.1,1.1 -e "IP Not Found" file1.txt file2.txt
```

`-i` means ignore case, `-t ,` means fields are separated by commas, `-1 1` means join on the first (only) field of the first file; `-2 2` means join on the second field of the second file. `-a 1` means include rows from the first file that don't have any matches. `-o 2.1,1.1` specifies the output format: the first field of the second file (IP), then the first field of the first file (AP). `-e "IP Not Found"` means to output "IP Not Found" in place of an empty field.

This will output

```
1.1.1.1,AP1
2.2.2.2,AP2
3.3.3.3,Ap3
4.4.4.4,AP4
IP Not Found,Ap5
6.6.6.6,Ap6
```

Comment: Alternatively, just load the data into sqlite and do the whole thing with one query :)

Comment: can also add -e "IP Not Found"

Comment: @amdixon oh, nice! I didn't see that one. Will update.

Comment: awesome, that worked very well, thanks! It only took .4 seconds to process the names too, very fast

Answer (score 1):

This awk snippet should do it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}
     (FNR==NR){a[tolower($2)]=$0}
     (FNR!=NR){if (a[tolower($1)]!="") 
                 print a[tolower($1)]
               else 
                 print "IP Not Found," $1}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

producing in your case:

```
1.1.1.1,Ap1
2.2.2.2,Ap2
3.3.3.3,Ap3
4.4.4.4,Ap4
IP Not Found,Ap5
6.6.6.6,Ap6
```